# I want to calculate how many pixel an object is getting smaller per mt

Tags: math

object is 960 px in width if we see it from 50 mt distance

same object is 90 px in width if we see it from 1300 mt distance

same object is _____ px in width if we see it from 1 mt distance

"Basically i need a formula to calculate "same object is _____ px in width if we see it from ____ mt distance"

Comment: That depends on the projection model. A common assumption is an inversely linear relationship between size and distance. However, this assumption does not hold in your example. So what is the assumption?

Comment: what distance? for perspective views it should be perpendicular distance to projection/view plane ... the formula is usually triangle similarity `size1/dist1 = size2/dist2`